# Google Directory API return outdated values

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-directory-api

I have a strange problem for about 2 weeks. My python script repeatedly (every 5 min) asking google directory api for  gsuite users. A would like find users who has enable 2 factor auth (isEnrolledIn2Sv)
Unfortunately when user turns on 2FA my script returns  isEnrolledIn2Sv=True only several hours later.

**When I asking it by gam ( https://github.com/jay0lee/GAM ) gets properly answer immediately.**

What going on? Some kind of cache? Why google return to me not actual data for several hours? It is possible that my python library versions have bugs?

My python code:

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import googleapiclient.discovery
...
...
...

#inside class:

    def run(self):
        log("Start no2faMonitor ")
        while (True):
            log("checking no2fa list")
            self.get_google_token()
            self.ask_google_user()
            log("Users in no2fa with 2-step verification: {}".format(len(self.users)))
            for u in self.users:
                self.send_notify(u)
            time.sleep(274)

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def get_google_token(self):

        credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(config.ServiceAccountFile, scopes=config.GoogleScopes).with_subject(config.SubjectAccount)
        self.directory = googleapiclient.discovery.build('admin', 'directory_v1', credentials=credentials)

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def ask_google_user(self):

        results = self.directory.users().list(customer="my_customer", query="orgUnitPath=/no2fa", maxResults=500).execute()
        self.userdata = json.loads(json.dumps(results))
        for element in self.userdata['users']:
            log("user: {}, 2fa: {}".format(element['primaryEmail'], element['isEnrolledIn2Sv']))

...
...
...
```

element['isEnrolledIn2Sv'] contain "False" for users with turned on 2FA.

```
**pip3 list | grep google**
google                   2.0.1                 
google-api-python-client 1.7.4                 
google-auth              1.5.1                 
google-auth-httplib2     0.0.3
```

Before about 2 weeks everythink worked OK, Good answers I recived after 5 min

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunley my last answer is not true. 
I found right way to solve this issue.

After change metod form list() to get() all returned data is up to date.

list() should be used only to get user list, not it's parameters

```
results = self.directory.users().list(customer="my_customer", query="orgUnitPath=/no2fa", maxResults=500).execute()
```

unfortunley get() needs one requset per user.

```
getuser = self.directory.users().get(userKey=element['primaryEmail'], projection="full").execute()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found cache parameter in python library. (default is True)

```
build(serviceName, version, http=None, discoveryServiceUrl=DISCOVERY_URI, developerKey=None, model=None, requestBuilder=HttpRequest, credentials=None, cache_discovery=True, cache=None) 
Construct a Resource for interacting with an API.
```

verified patch:

```
- self.directory = googleapiclient.discovery.build('admin', 'directory_v1', credentials=credentials)
+ self.directory = googleapiclient.discovery.build('admin', 'directory_v1', credentials=credentials, cache_discovery=False)
```